# How x?y:a?b:c will be evaluated?

Tags: c

Associativity of conditional operator is from right to left so the right most conditional operator should be solved(testing whether a is true or not) first but the  book mentions that first x will be tested

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

Comment: Yes it's a little confusing because the operator precedence applies to the line as a whole, whereas the right-to-left / left-to-right processing applies internally to the operator or statement.

Comment: Precedence is about grouping, not execution order. It is like inserting parentheses. Putting parentheses around a subexpression does not make it execute any sooner.

Comment: Associativity only determines what is an operand of what operator. It has little to do with evaluation order.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that the conditional operator associates to the right means that `x?y:a?b:c` will be parsed as if it had been written `x?y:(a?b:c)`. If it associated to the left, it would have been parsed as `(x?y:a)?b:c`, which would almost certainly have been a surprise (unless you are used to PHP).

But neither of these parentheses change execution *order*. The conditional operator's first operand is always evaluated first.

Answer (score 1):

The expression

```
int result = x?y:a?b:c;
```

can be written as

```
int result;
if (x)
{
    result = y;
}
else
{
    if (a)
    {
        result = b;
    }
    else
    {
        result = c;
    }
}
```

So `x` must be evaluated first to determine whether the `if` block or the `else` block will be executed.

---

Note that the ternary operator only evaluates the expression that it needs to. When `x` is true, `y` is evaluated. When `x` is false, the subexpression `a?b:c` is evaluated.

In fact, the C standard requires that the code only evaluate the expression that's needed. Here's what it says in section 6.5.15/p4:

> The first operand is evaluated; there is a sequence point between its
>   evaluation and the evaluation of the second or third operand
>   (whichever is evaluated). The second operand is evaluated only if the
>   first compares unequal to 0; the third operand is evaluated only if
>   the first compares equal to 0; the result is the value of the second
>   or third operand (whichever is evaluated), converted to the type
>   described below.

In the expression `x?y:a?b:c`,

- the first operand is `x`
- the second operand is `y`
- the third operand is `a?b:c`

So the standard expressly forbids the code from evaluating any part of `a?b:c` unless `x` compares equal to 0.

---

The associativity only determines how the operands are interpreted. The first, second, and third operands listed above are based on right-to-left associativity.

If the associativity of the ternary operator was left-to-right, then

- the first operand would be `x?y:a`
- the second operand would be `b`
- the third operand would be `c`

Comment: But still I have question why x is evaluated first and not a?